# When is the finite nilpotent group cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotence

In the notion of nilpotent group, a finite group $G$ is nilpotent $\iff$ every Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$ $\iff$ $G$ is isomorphic to direct products of all Sylow subgroups of $G$.

Under what conditions is $G$ cyclic?

I have trouble in the case that $G\cong P_{1}\times P_{2}\times P_{3}$, where each $P_{i}$ are the Sylow subgroups of $G$ of order $4,27,5$, respectively.

Comment: A finite nilpotent group is cyclic iff all its Sylow subgroups are.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Under the assumption "$G$ is Galois", it is still not true that $G$ is cyclic, right?

Comment: "$G$ is Galois" is conjecturally a vacuous statement for a finite group.